# Фильтрация в Elasticsearch по пустому terms

Tags: elasticsearch

Извините, может вопрос уже где то есть, но я не смог найти.
Есть документы такого вида:

```
"_source": {
    "id": "6521",
    "categories": {
      "ids": [
        7041,
        7051
      ]
    },
    "id": "6525",
    "categories": {
      "ids": []
    },
}
```

Мне нужно получить те документы у которых categories.ids не имеют значений.
Я не смог найти как задать "terms" для такого случая.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [Exists Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html) в сочетании с bool must_not:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must_not": {
                "exists" : { "field" : "categories.ids" }
            }
        }
    }
}
```